Why does air bubbles form when it is poured on another liquid surface
Reason behind the formation of air bubbles .
Force dynamics bw water and air
And how long does it take the air bubbles to pop and what factor the popping depends.

I don't know the answer, but maybe the answer contains the word, "entrainment." Something you might try searching for.
